# Table sorting not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have added sorting functionality on a table. I collected this functionality from:

this : **[LINK](http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/)**

It's working fine on every browser but not in IE 7. I am not good in jQuery and not finding the reason why not working.

Here is **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/q378X/)** link what I did. Is there any way to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

**js**

```
$(function () {
    // Helper function to convert a string of the form "Mar 15, 1987" into
    // a Date object.
    var date_from_string = function (str) {
        var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul",
            "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
        var pattern = "^([a-zA-Z]{3})\\s*(\\d{2}),\\s*(\\d{4})$";
        var re = new RegExp(pattern);
        var DateParts = re.exec(str).slice(1);

        var Year = DateParts[2];
        var Month = $.inArray(DateParts[0].toLowerCase(), months);
        var Day = DateParts[1];
        return new Date(Year, Month, Day);
    }

    var moveBlanks = function (a, b) {
        if (a < b) {
            if (a == "") return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            if (b == "") return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
    var moveBlanksDesc = function (a, b) {
        // Blanks are by definition the smallest value, so we don't have to
        // worry about them here
        if (a < b) return 1;
        if (a > b) return -1;
        return 0;
    };

    var table = $("table").stupidtable({
        "date": function (a, b) {
            // Get these into date objects for comparison.

            aDate = date_from_string(a);
            bDate = date_from_string(b);

            return aDate - bDate;
        },
            "moveBlanks": moveBlanks,
            "moveBlanksDesc": moveBlanksDesc,
    });

    table.on("beforetablesort", function (event, data) {
        // data.column - the index of the column sorted after a click
        // data.direction - the sorting direction (either asc or desc)
        $("#msg").text("Sorting index " + data.column)
    });

    table.on("aftertablesort", function (event, data) {
        var th = $(this).find("th");
        th.find(".arrow").remove();
        var dir = $.fn.stupidtable.dir;

        var arrow = data.direction === dir.ASC ? "&uarr;" : "&darr;";
        th.eq(data.column).append('<span class="arrow">' + arrow + '</span>');
    });

    $("tr").slice(1).click(function () {
        $(".awesome").removeClass("awesome");
        $(this).addClass("awesome");
    });

});
```

Comment: For those of us without IE7, are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 does not like dangling `,`

Change

```
"moveBlanksDesc": moveBlanksDesc,
```

to

```
"moveBlanksDesc": moveBlanksDesc
                          //    ^ remove the trailing ,
```

Comment: Wow , It worked and working perfectly in IE 7 ... Thank a ton.

Comment: Whoops, my Python is leaking! Good catch.

Comment: @JoeQuery That does not sound too good. You need to go see a doctor :P